# connection can not be resolved for a type when work in an environment of Tomcat, JDBC and Eclipse

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc, oracle11g

```
 <%
     String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";// 1. 

Load the driver
    Class.forName(driver);
    // 2. Define the connection URL
    String url = 

"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"; //orcl is the 

SID
    String myusername = "test4"; // Your DB login ID
    String mypassword = "test4"; //Your Db pass
    // 3. Establish the connection
    Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection

(url, test4,test4);
    %>
```

here is the code a page call display.jsp
I use oracle express, its application user:system

pw:systempw
schema user:test4, password:test4

I try to connect to one of the table in the schema

test4, table named: update_time_schedule_reader

to display its content in a query, but I can not even

establish a connection....

how can I do this? I am totally lost.
Please provide step by step instruction if possible.

I will be really appreciated!

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have any logs? Try to system.out.println to see steps, and try to find where the problem is happening? (driver not in classpath, user,password not correct, etc ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` should have the data source entry like

```
<context>
<!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->  
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container"  
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="test4" password="test4"  
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"  
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:db"  
    maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" />  
</context>
```

Also, the JSP page should look something like-

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>  
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context"   %>  
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"   %>  
<%@page import="javax.naming.NamingException"   %>  
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"   %> 

 <%  
 Context initCtx = new InitialContext();  
 DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB");  
 Connection conn = ds.getConnection();  

     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
     String query="select * from schema.table";  

    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);  
    while (result.next())  
     {  
       //.....Loop through data set and do something
  %>
```

Go through [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) link for more details.